# Code - C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

I don't know how to convert this code to VB

```
if ((string)Session["type"] != "administrator")
{
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Especially, which part?

Comment: Voting to close. OP not supporting question. bye bye.

Answer (score 2):

[Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/)

```
If DirectCast(Session("type"), String) <> "administrator" Then
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
End If
```

Comment: If String.Compare(TryCast(Session("type"), String), "administrator", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then

Answer (score 0):

Here is a converted code:

```
If DirectCast(Session("type"), String) <> "administrator" Then
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx")
End If
```